# How can I solve python nasdaqdatalink usage error?

Tags: python, nasdaq-api

I want to use nasdaqdatalink for my project. But when I run the code below I get error. The error given below. How can I solve it?

The code:

```
import nasdaqdatalink
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import matplotlib.dates

style.use('ggplot')

api_key = 'xyz'
nasdaqdatalink.apiconfig = api_key

df = nasdaqdatalink.get('BITFINEX/BTCUSD')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\UYGULAMALAR\PyCharm 2023.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\UYGULAMALAR\PyCharm 2023.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nasdaqdatalink'
```

Comment: if `pip install nasdaq-data-link` didnt work, you can use conda like this: `conda install nasdaq-data-link`

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the module is not found. You may try to install the module with this from Powershell in your project path:

```
pip install nasdaq-data-link
```

Comment: I installed it. I will try again. The usage of api config `nasdaqdatalink.apiconfig = api_key` is true ? @Tahirhan

Comment: If you can not resolve the module installation issue, you can create a project folder on a C disk and try that path.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the module nasdaqdatalink

```
pip install Nasdaq-Data-Link
```

https://pypi.org/project/Nasdaq-Data-Link/